# Sort dataframe columns by day of the week

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I created a pivot table with days of the week as columns, and I want to order the columns by day of week: Sunday, Monday, etc.

```
piv = reports.pivot_table(index='DayOfWeek',columns='Category',aggfunc='size',fill_value=0)
```

returns
[this table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THtXN.png)

How do I go about this?

Comment: Change `df['Day of Week'] = df['Day of Week'].astype('category', categories=cats, ordered=True)` to `df.columns = df.columns.astype('category', categories=cats, ordered=True)` and then `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)`

Comment: @jezrael i get the error astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categories'

Comment: Is possible use `df.columns = pd.CategoricalIndex(df.columns, categories=cats, ordered=True)` ?

Comment: @jezrael no error, but the columns still aren't sorted :(

Comment: do you add `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` ?

Comment: @jezrael worked! thank you so so much